# Huge gap between two methods of measuring request time via python-requests

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I am trying to measure the respone time of a certain request using python-requests.

```
import requests
import time

start = time.time()
r = requests.get("https://www.dl.soc.i.kyoto-u.ac.jp/index.php/members/")
end = time.time()

print(end - start)
print(r.elapsed.seconds)
```

It gave me a result of

```
64.67747116088867
0.631163
```

Could anyone please explain the reason of this huge gap? Thanks.
By the way, when I was trying the same request on Google-Chrome, actually the first result is what I want.

Comment: Did you read e.g. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.elapsed? There are other things happening *outside* that (establishing the connection, parsing the response) that will not be counted. You can use e.g. cURL to get some more info on these times, see https://overloaded.io/timing-http-requests-curl

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I did. But still have no idea where this gap comes from. Any idea?

Comment: Given that, as far as I understand it, requests parses the response lazily, I'd guess it's related to the connection. But I've given you a tool to investigate this; have a look and find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some test with an artificially delaying webserver:

```
nc -l 8080
```

Then in another terminal in a Python session:

```
import time, requests
a=time.time()
r = requests.get("http://localhost:8080/")
b=time.time()
print r.elapsed, b-a
```

Pasting this issued this HTTP request on the server terminal:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.9.1
```

I waited for 5 seconds, then I pasted this reply in the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 12
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=15
Date: Thu, 04 Jan 2018 10:12:09 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Wed, 09 Dec 2015 13:57:24 GMT
ETag: "28bd-52677784b6090"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

hello
```

I stated 12 bytes but only sent 6 (`hello\n`), so this was unfinished.  I waited another five seconds, then pasted this text:

```
world
```

This finished the reply with the remaining six bytes (`world\n`).  In the client terminal I saw the result appear:

```
0:00:05.185509 10.8904578686
```

So, obviously the `r.elapsed` is the Time-To-First-Byte (TTFB) while the call to `requests.get()` only terminates after the whole message has been received (Time-To-Last-Byte, TTLB).

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot. But any idea for the common reasons of 1min gap between TTFB and TTLB?

Comment: Sure.  Your server starts responding at once but needs ~64 seconds to complete the answer.  Maybe it's very large or takes a lot of time to be prepared before it can be sent to you (complex DB query or whatever).